# Configure Phoenix for Dynamic Endpoint URLs on Heroku

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm confused on how the `host:` parameter in the Endpoint configuration in Phoenix works.

I'm deploying to different Heroku apps (prod and staging) with different URLs, respectively. I want to configure the Host URL to be dynamic, coming from an environment variable, like so:

```
config :testapp, TestApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: {:system, "HOST"}, port: 443],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

However, after deploy, my asset URLs no longer have the unique hash set by `phoenix.digest`, which is a deal breaker.

Interestingly, when I hardcode the URL:

```
config :testapp, TestApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "someapp-staging.herokuapp.com", port: 443],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

Even if it doesn't match the Heroku app url, everything still seems to work fine, and the asset URLs are correct. E.g. I can deploy to an app with an URL `foo.herokuapp.com` and everything still works.

The configuration above is from `prod.exs`, I'm using the elixir and phoenix static custom buildpacks, with the following config:

```
# elixir_buildpack.config

# Elixir version
elixir_version=1.2.3

# Always rebuild from scratch on every deploy?
always_rebuild=true

# ENV variables
config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL HOST)
```

and

```
# phoenix_static_buildpack.config

# We can set the version of Node to use for the app here
node_version=5.10.0

# We can set the version of NPM to use for the app here
npm_version=3.8.3

# ENV variables
config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL HOST)
```

I could probably introduce a separate `staging.exs` config file and set `MIX_ENV=staging`, but I would like to understand:

1) Why using `{:system, "HOST"}` breaks digested asset URLs

2) Why any string works fine on different applications and URLs

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not have an environment variable named `HOST` by default (though `PORT` is available). I'd double check that you've added it as a config variable in your Heroku settings.

The command `heroku run printenv` is handy as it will output both base environment variables and config vars added manually or by add-ons.

Comment: Hi Mike — thanks for your suggestion; I have indeed the HOST variable added to my Heroku app (I added it myself and set it to the correct domain URL) so that seems fine.

Comment: Well, sorry that didn't work. Separately, why are you trying to define the HOST anyway, shouldn't the assets just load relative to the root?

Comment: I checked the source code documentation and it looks like the assets are using the Host URL if the static_url key is not set: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L140